# How to give documents link in the site

Tags: visualforce, force.com-sites

I want to create a site where i am giving links for documents.there is one document named "leave policy" which i am showing as a link in the site.but whenever i am clicking on the link it is asking for salesforce login.

So is there any other way i can do this?

Comment: So you need to document to be publicly available not just to SF users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create public URL for file first. Here is details 
Make uploaded document public:

```
Upload file in files object.
Go to file list view and click on sharing setting
```

[image]

From sharing settings click on 'Share with anyone', it will create a link. This link is public you can use it anywhere.

[How to create public file](http://sdfclight.blogspot.in/)

Comment: While the article behind the link may contain an answer, this post should be self-contained, i.e. it should contain enough information to be useful even if the link disappears or the blog is populated with other material which obscures the instructions which are currently at the top of the page.